# Amplify init UnauthorizedException

Tags: angular, aws-amplify, init

I am learning about amplifier using below documentation
https://docs.amplify.aws/angular/start/getting-started/installation/
https://docs.amplify.aws/angular/start/getting-started/setup/

But while executing "amplify init" command with required details it gives error as

```
UnauthorizedException.


As per 1st documentation link, successfully performed "amplify configure"
```

.

Then performed steps given in 2nd link for "amplify init" with below details

```
Project information
| Name: Amplify-App
| Environment: dev
| Default editor: Visual Studio Code
| App type: javascript
| Javascript framework: angular
| Source Directory Path: src
| Distribution Directory Path: dist
| Build Command: npm.cmd run-script build
| Start Command: ng serve

? Initialize the project with the above configuration? Yes
Using default provider  awscloudformation
? Select the authentication method you want to use: AWS profile

For more information on AWS Profiles, see:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html

? Please choose the profile you want to use **default**

After this error is displayed as below
**We are unable to process your request. Please reach out to your support representative.**
```

After debugging using:

```
 "amplify init --debug" below UnauthorizedException error is displayed
ProjectInitFault: We are unable to process your request. Please reach out to your support representative.
    at init (C:\snapshot\amplify-cli\build\node_modules\@aws-amplify\amplify-provider-awscloudformation\lib\amplify-service-manager.js:163:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object.run (C:\snapshot\amplify-cli\build\node_modules\@aws-amplify\amplify-provider-awscloudformation\lib\initializer.js:96:9)

We are unable to process your request. Please reach out to your support representative.
UnauthorizedException: We are unable to process your request. Please reach out to your support representative.
    at Object.extractError (C:\snapshot\amplify-cli\build\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\protocol\json.js:80:27)
    at Request.extractError (C:\snapshot\amplify-cli\build\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\protocol\rest_json.js:61:8)
    at Request.callListeners (C:\snapshot\amplify-cli\build\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (C:\snapshot\amplify-cli\build\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (C:\snapshot\amplify-cli\build\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:686:14)
    at Request.transition (C:\snapshot\amplify-cli\build\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (C:\snapshot\amplify-cli\build\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
    at C:\snapshot\amplify-cli\build\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\amplify-cli\build\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\amplify-cli\build\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:688:12)
    at Request.callListeners (C:\snapshot\amplify-cli\build\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:116:18)
    at Request.emit (C:\snapshot\amplify-cli\build\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (C:\snapshot\amplify-cli\build\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:686:14)
    at Request.transition (C:\snapshot\amplify-cli\build\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (C:\snapshot\amplify-cli\build\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
    at C:\snapshot\amplify-cli\build\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\amplify-cli\build\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\amplify-cli\build\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:688:12)
    at Request.callListeners (C:\snapshot\amplify-cli\build\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:116:18)
    at callNextListener (C:\snapshot\amplify-cli\build\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:96:12)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\snapshot\amplify-cli\build\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\event_listeners.js:417:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

I checked access key and secret key stored in C:/Users/user/.aws/credentials file and keys are same as generated while creating IAM User.

How to debug further to resolve above issue?

Comment: It's telling you to reach out to your support representative.  Did you do that?

Comment: Reported to support center and waiting for their reply. Till then if there is any way to identify issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported issue in AWS Support Center.
As per instructions given by support center I did following

1. Changed root user password and also implemented MFA.
2. Checked CloudTrail logs for any unusual activity. In my case there is not logs present.
3. Checked unauthorized access (if any) in Billing section. There is no unauthorized access.

"amplify init" is started working after performing Step 1.